# set parent height/width according to child in display flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm using Flexbox, but there seems to be a problem when i try set the parent divs height/width to be auto.

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) Guide,

```css
.parent {
    background: #000;
    width:100px;     /* I WANT TO SET THIS AUTO ** NOT FIX 100PX** */
    height:100px;    /* I WANT TO SET THIS AUTO ** NOT FIX 100PX** */
}

.child {
    display: flex;
    color:white;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 50px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>a</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

i also try this,

```
.parent {
    background: #000;
    flex:1;
}
```

But it colored only one row of child items,

There is problem to set parent background color as per child record width,
how to set width auto with Flexbox.

Is it possible to find out the width using JavaScript and set the parent width?

Please could you suggest best practice to arrange the item as per max-height of the div.

Comment: Obvious typo : `. parent` (remove space). Flexbox is not easy to use, I have set up a [little toy to play around with it](http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/xbaPgM), if it can help you.

Comment: Remove the space between the `.` and `parent`.

Comment: @JeremyThille  ya there is problem in typo but its not my solutions..Thanks!!

Comment: What is you expected output?

Comment: @ketan i want to set parent div height/width auto, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is few issues that you need to address. Based on your style, the ".child" is the flex container and `<li>` elements are the flex items.

1. `<li>` cannot be nested in `<div>`. It needs to be used with `<ul>` or `<ol>`.
2. I think you ".child" is the container flex box. If you are using IE11 you can
   "display:-ms-flexbox" work (not display:flex)(display:flexbox has no effect in IE11)
3. remove "max-height:50px;" it limits the size of the container box (.child). you are containing `<li>`. you set flex-direction to column so `<li>` elements will be listed from top to down. then you can remove (.parent width and height.)
4. Now if you are trying to have the size of the .child equal the size of its element then you need to look at more margin:0px and display:inline-block attributes for child elements.